Flutter Drift sqllite3 not able to migrate data to the next version because of some runtime error
I followed the tutorial here: https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/migrations/
When I try to bump the schema to version 2 by adding a migration statement, I get a runtime error. I am not expecting the Db statements to run at runtime but before the database is read. Not sure what I am doing wrong.
My before migration code is as follows:
  ...
//IntColumn get listPosition => integer().withDefault(const Constant(0))(); // to be added in version 2

      @override
      int get schemaVersion => 1;

  @override
  MigrationStrategy get migration{
    return MigrationStrategy(
      onCreate: (Migrator m) async{
        await m.createAll();
      },
      onUpgrade: (Migrator m, int from, int to) async {
        await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF');
        await transaction(() async {
          if (from < 2) {
           // for version 2
            //await m.addColumn(notes, notes.listPosition as GeneratedColumn<Object>);
          }
          
        });

      },
      beforeOpen: (details) async {
        await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
        // ....
      },
    );
  }

When I uncomment the following lines and bump the schema to 2:
  IntColumn get listPosition => integer().withDefault(const Constant(0))(); // Added in version 2
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 2;

  @override
  MigrationStrategy get migration{
    return MigrationStrategy(
      ...
      onUpgrade: (Migrator m, int from, int to) async {
        await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF');
        await transaction(() async {
          if (from < 2) {
          
           await m.addColumn(notes, notes.listPosition as GeneratedColumn<Object>);
          }
         
        });

      },
      beforeOpen: (details) async {
        await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
        // ....
      },
    );
  }

The runtime error I get:
Unsupported operation: This method should not be called at runtime. Are you sure you re-ran the builder after changing your tables or databases?
I/flutter (20447): #0      _isGenerated (package:drift/src/dsl/dsl.dart:35:3)
I/flutter (20447): #1      Table.integer (package:drift/src/dsl/table.dart:117:35)
I/flutter (20447): #2      Notes.listPosition (package:myapp/data/notes.dart:24:33)
I/flutter (20447): #3      NoteDB.migration.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:myapp/data/notes.dart:49:44)
I/flutter (20447): #4      DatabaseConnectionUser.transaction.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:drift/src/runtime/api/connection_user.dart:465:38)
I/flutter (20447): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:13)
I/flutter (20447): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1301:19)
I/flutter (20447): #7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1804:10)
I/flutter (20447): #8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1747:10)
I/flutter (20447): #9      DatabaseConnectionUser._runConnectionZoned (package:drift/src/runtime/api/connection_user.dart:532:12)
I/flutter (20447): #10     DatabaseConnectionUser.transaction.<anonymous closure> (package:drift/src/runtime/api/connection_user.dart:462:14)
I/flutter (20447): #11     DatabaseConnectionUser.doWhenOpened.<anonymous closure> (package:drift/src/runtime/api/connection_user.dart:162:64)
I/flutter (20447): #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:
I/flutter (20447): ----------------------------------------------------

